# setup.py requires MySQL-python

Tags: python, setup.py

I'm writing a `setup.py` script and want to specify a dependency onto MySQL package:

```
requires=['requests', 'mock', 'GitPython', 'MySQL-python']
```

But `MySQL-python` looks to be illegal for setup tool because it thinks that after `-` there should be a version and it throws this error:

> ValueError: expected parenthesized list: '-python'

What can I do here?

*Environment: Python 2.7.3; precise 32*

Answer (score 1):

From the [distutils documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html#relationships-between-distributions-and-packages):

> To specify that any version of a module or package is required, the
>   string should consist entirely of the module or package name. Examples
>   include 'mymodule' and 'xml.parsers.expat'.

With that in mind you should just be able to check off MySQL-python's `_mysql` module:

```
requires=['requests', 'mock', 'GitPython', '_mysql']
```

Answer (score 0):

On this point you should not follow the distutils documentation.  `requires` comes from a PEP defining metadata for distributions, but it does not actually work with any tool, including distutils.  For now, you need to choose a packaging tool that’s not in the standard library and use its conventions for defining dependencies and build-time dependencies.  pip has requirements files; distribute has requires_dist and setup_requires; buildout has something else, etc.

Comment: You suggest to use `pip install -r requirements.txt`, right? But then I can't provide users with an easy-to-use package, users don't like to think, they want just to run `pip install myapp`. Or do you have other suggestions?